# Can't EXTRACT year of the date with BigQuery | error:No matching signature for function EXTRACT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract the year of a date in order to calculate the age of user.
The 'birthday' is a string format in YYYY-MM-DD.

Here is my code

```
SELECT username, birthday, CURRENT_DATE(),
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM birthday) as age ,    
    FROM 
        `user`;
```

My SQL table 'user':

| username | birthday |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 1999-05-11 |
| Name2 | 1999-05-11 |

But the "EXTRACT(YEAR FROM birthday)" don't work and I don't find where is the problem.

The complete error :

No matching signature for function EXTRACT for argument types: DATE_TIME_PART FROM STRING. Supported signatures: EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM DATE); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM TIMESTAMP [AT TIME ZONE STRING]); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM DATETIME); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM TIME); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM INTERVAL) at [2:41]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below

```
select username, birthday, current_date(),
extract(year from current_date()) - extract(year from date(birthday)) as age ,    
from `user`;
```

Note `date(birthday)` to fix a "problem"